# Passing value from Page to UserControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

Good day. I have a trouble with pass data between webform and UserControl.

I have the webform webform1.aspx. And i have a component GridView1. I also have UserControl -  grdControl.ascx.

In webform1.aspx i mention UserControl:

```
<uc1:grdcontrol runat="server" id="grdControl" />
```

Also webform1.aspx.cs contains an event

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     grdControl.SelectedValue = GridView1.SelectedValue.ToString();
  }
```

In turn UserControl grdControl.ascx.cs contains the following code:

```
private string _selectedValue;        
public string SelectedValue         
{            
  get { return _selectedValue; }            
  set { _selectedValue = value; }
}
```

In grdControl.ascx i use label and i try to get value SelectedValue and use it as text for Label1.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# SelectedValue%>' ></asp:Label>
```

But is don't work correctly. In a web page i see nothing.

Comment: `<%#` is generally used for things like `asp:Repeater` or `asp:GridView`, etc... things that have a data repeater, so you'd use `<%#Container...%>` for instance.  Try using just a simple `DataBind()` in your page load function, which might work

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use `Label2.Text = SelectedValue` in the codebehind of the user control?

Comment: @freefaller - Thanks a lot for clarification about using <%#! I realized that i will use Label2.Text = SelectedValue. In this case it will work fine. But i still do not understand how exactly i can use some variable value right in ascx or aspx file.

That if i want use something like this:

    <SelectParameters>
      <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="<%# SelectedValue %>" Name="WorkOrderID" Type="Int32">
    </asp:Parameter>
</SelectParameters>

Answer (score 0):

Setting the value of the label in the PreRender event of the code behind should fix it.

I'm thinking that GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged will get called after the Page_Load event of the inner grid control that's why the value is blank because you are trying to set it in the page itself and that happens in the Pre_init function of the inner control. I don't think SelectedValue would be set at that point.